# How to customize leaflet popup to include image thumbnails and other customization?

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, popup

I have searched around but none of the solutions seems to work. I am trying to add a title, image, address and name dynamically as data comes in to popups on my leaflet map but am not getting anywhere.

here is my typescript code:

```
refresh() {
  this.artworkService.retrieveAll().then((artworkList) => {
    this.artworkList = artworkList;
    for (let artwork of this.artworkList) {
      var popupInfo = "<span class='test'>" + artwork.name + "</span>" + "<br/>" + artwork.filename;
      console.log(artwork.name);
      L.marker([artwork.latitude, artwork.longitude], this.markerIcon).addTo(this.map)
      .bindPopup(popupInfo);
    }
  });
}
```

here i tried to wrap the title around a span and was hoping to add some css to it but doesn't do anything! any tips would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most possibly the markers are not rendered because you are declaring the `markerIcon` in a wrong way. It should be for instance:

```
markerIcon = {
    icon: L.icon({
      iconSize: [25, 41],
      iconAnchor: [10, 41],
      popupAnchor: [2, -40],
      // specify the path here
      iconUrl: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/images/marker-icon.png",
      shadowUrl: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/images/marker-shadow.png"
    })
};
```

Second, to apply custom css on the popup you need to provide `popupOptions` in the `bindPopup` method or instantiate a `L.popup` and attach a classname. Check also [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262053/multiple-popup-styles-for-leaflet). First way would be:

```
const popupOptions = {
  className: "test"
};
for (let artwork of this.artworkList) {
  const popupInfo =
    "<span class=''>" +
    artwork.name +
    "</span>" +
    "<br/>" +
    artwork.filename;
  console.log(artwork.name);
  L.marker([artwork.latitude, artwork.longitude], this.markerIcon)
    .addTo(this.map)
    .bindPopup(popupInfo, popupOptions);
}
```

and then include the style in the global style.css

for instance:

```
.test .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
      background: #2ce897;
      color: #eee;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 24px;
      border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/7m47okwz16) with an example of your user case.

Comment: How could I add more than just one class?

Comment: `const popupOptions = { className: "test test2" };` I modified the demo. Please accept and/or upvote the answer if it helped you.